# How to set your YouTube name to nothing?

Tags: youtube, google-account

So there's [this YouTuber](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmOiT9ZnSvLZ1XMBFjGiNmQ/about) with the username of literally nothing.  However, when I try to set my username to " " (just a space), Google doesn't like that. When I just don't put a username, Google doesn't like it either. If it's not possible, then how does that person do it?

Note: when I inspected their username (using ctrl + shift + c), I found that it said  `&zwnj;`. I have no idea what that means though.

Comment: ZWNJ is a special character similar to a space but not actually a space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner

Comment: a simple Google search for "zwnj" should give the answer immediately

Comment: Yes but my point is how to set the name to nothing?

Comment: of course you can't set it to a space because a space and a ZWNJ space is completely different. You need to type the ZWNJ by either copying or by typing the correct Unicode code point with Alt code or something similar

Comment: Then how have they done it?

Answer (score 1):

`&zwnj;` is an HTML script that means a special character. That character is Unicode 200C, which is named "Zero width non-joiner". He must have an old youtube channel because I can't seem to figure out how that is possible now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/156078)